# How can I delete all rows from a class using Parse's PHP library?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am running a cron job on my server that is running a PHP to script that should delete all the rows from a specific chart in my Parse database. I am using the new official Parse PHP library.

I've tried two different approaches so far, yet both approaches only manage to delete 60% of the rows.

Approach 1:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Chart");
$query->limit(1000);
$results = $query->find();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 
    $object = $results[$i];
    $object->destroy();
}

$query2 = new ParseQuery("Chart");
$query2->limit(1000);
$results = $query2->find();
if (count($results) != 0) {
    deleteRows();
}
echo "Finished a loop";
}
```

Approach 2:

```
$query3 = new ParseQuery("Chart");

$query3->each(function($obj) {
    $obj->destroy();
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Two things that I think could be causing the problem but I'm not sure is the server is limiting the execution time of the PHP script or if there is more than 1000 rows I would need to run the process more than once?

Answer (score 1):

I use Parse with PHP for my Web apps.
This example here may help:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseException;

$candidato = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['username']);
$candidato = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['post']);

if($candidato && $username){

try{
    ParseClient::initialize($app_id, $rest_key, $master_key);

$query = new ParseQuery('like');    
    $query->equalTo("user", $username);
    $query->equalTo("post", $post);  

        $res = $query->find();        

        $object;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++) {
            $object = $res[$i];
        }

$object->destroy();

echo "object destroyed succesfully";

} catch (ParseException $ex) {

echo $ex->getMessage();

}

}else{
 echo "not enough params";
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to see if there are more results, and while this flag is set, loop again.

```
$not_finished = true;
while ($not_finished){
    $query = new ParseQuery("Chart");
    $query->limit(1000);
    $results = $query->find();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 
        $object = $results[$i];
        $object->destroy();
    }

    $query2 = new ParseQuery("Chart");
    $query2->limit(1000);
    $results = $query2->find();
    if (count($results) != 0) {
        deleteRows();
    }
    echo "Finished a loop";
    }

    $query = new ParseQuery("Chart");
    $result = $query->find();
    if (count($result) > 0){
        $not_finished = true;
    }
    else{
        $not_finished = false;
    }
}
```